# Build IPA from .APP bundle without xcworkspace

Tags: ios, xamarin, command-line, ipa, xcodebuild

There used to be a way to build an IPA from an .APP bundle using xcrun but Apple, for some reason, has deprecated PackageApplication.  I'm left only with xcodebuild, which requires an Xcode workspace file.  My .APP wasn't created via xcode.  It was made with Visual Studio for Mac with Xamarin.  I can make an IPA by exporting an archive from the IDE but what I'm trying to do is build the IPA from the command line and sign it.  The signing part is very straightforward but I don't know how to build the IPA without ZIPping it manually, adding in the embedded.mobileprovision, etc.

Is there an alternative to xcbuild PackageApplication that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to do is build the IPA from the command line...

You can use `msbuild` to build/package an `.ipa`

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/msbuild \
  AStackOverflowSolution.sln \
  /p:Configuration=Ad-Hoc \
  /p:Platform=iPhone \
  /p:BuildIpa=true
```

re: [Building via the Command Line (On Mac)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=macos#building-via-the-command-line-on-mac)

For Windows, include the `ServerAddress` and `ServerUser` of your macOS build system

```
/p:ServerAddress="192.168.40.40" 
/p:ServerUser="YourmacRemoteSSHuser"
```

re: [IPA Support in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=macos)

Comment: Oh wow!! thank you so much!  I am actually already using msbuild to make the project.  However, I was only passing my .csproj and not passing any arguments.  I can see you have BuildIpa = true and some other stuff.  I need to do that.  I'll try this now.

Comment: @iPaul There is a full list of all the msbuild props at the link in my answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get this to work but without the Configuration=Ad-Hoc.  That caused an error saying no output directory is specified.  I tried just the BuildIpa and Platform and it worked.  Well, not quite yet, I have a "No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain." error I need to work through but I know it will create an IPA now once I fix that.

Comment: @iPaul in terms of  `/p:Configuration=Ad-Hoc`, you might or might not have that `Configuration` defined that in your solution/project, it might be a "Release" configuration, or a custom configuration that defines compiler directives, different info.plist for testing, etc...

Comment: Haha I feel stupid.  I knew it should be Release (and I always select that in the IDE) but I didn't realize that's what this argument was specifying.  It worked perfectly. I guess I did have my cert and prov profile right because I have an IPA now.  Thanks again!